# How do I cancel a StreamSubscription inside a Cubit?

Tags: flutter, bloc, cubit

I have a cubit that listens to a stream of messages, and emits a state which holds the messages.
In the screen, I am using a BlocProvider to access the cubit, and a BlocBuilder to display
the messages.

In instances like below, do I need to close the StreamSubscription created on listen()? Is there a clean way to do it?

```
class MessageCubit extends Cubit<MessageState> {
  final GetMessagesUseCase getMessagesUseCase;
  MessageCubit({this.getMessagesUseCase}) : super(MessageInitial());
  Future<void> getMessages({String senderId, String recipientId}) async {
    emit(MessageLoading());
    try {
      final messagesStreamData = getMessagesUseCase.call();

      //This is where I listen to a stream
      messagesStreamData.listen((messages) {
        emit(MessageLoaded(messages: messages));
      });


    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      emit(MessageFailure());
    } catch (_) {
      emit(MessageFailure());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't **need** to close the subscription, but you should as good practice to avoid potential memory leaks. Since it is so straightforward it's not any sacrifice.

1. Create a class variable of type `StreamSubscription<your type>`. Let's say it's named `sub`.
2. In getMessages before listen: `await sub?.cancel()`
3. Then `sub = messagesStreamData.listen(...`
4. Override the Cubit's `close` method and run the same command as in bullet 2.

Full code:

```
class MessageCubit extends Cubit<MessageState> {
  final GetMessagesUseCase getMessagesUseCase;

  // Added
  StreamSubscription<YOUR_MESSAGES_TYPE> sub;

  MessageCubit({this.getMessagesUseCase}) : super(MessageInitial());
  Future<void> getMessages({String senderId, String recipientId}) async {
    emit(MessageLoading());
    try {
      final messagesStreamData = getMessagesUseCase.call();

      // Added
      await sub?.cancel();
      //This is where I listen to a stream
      sub = messagesStreamData.listen((messages) {
        emit(MessageLoaded(messages: messages));
      });


    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      emit(MessageFailure());
    } catch (_) {
      emit(MessageFailure());
    }
  }

  // Added    
  @override
  Future<void> close() async {
    await sub?.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain the `await sub?.cancel()` inside `try{ }`? This does not appear intuitive to me to place a `cancel()` ahead of `listen()`

Comment: `getMessages()` could be called several times.

Comment: Now I get it - initially there is no sub (to be cancelled) and sub is assigned in the line after. Only on the 2nd call and later sub?.cancel becomes effective. Thanks!

Comment: That is correct